# onclick attribute in LinearLayour not working if containing ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a LinearLayout horizontally oriented, something like this:

o Some Text

where the "o" represents an ImageButton and "Some Text" a TextView. I added an attribute to the LinearLayout like:

```
android:onClick="doSomething"
```

this triggers if I click anywhere but over the ImageButton. I tried making the ImageButton clickable with the specific attribute but nothing changes. I'd like the user to be able to click on anything inside the layout to fire "doSomething".

My question is: what should I do so that the user can click on anything inside the LinearLayout to fire "doSomething" ?

Everything works fine as long as the user doesn't click over the ImageButton, in that case nothing happens.

**EDIT**: ImageButton not ImageView

Comment: Where do you use this layout? On Activity or on Fragment? Could you post code of your Activity?

Comment: Please post your layout code too. Is your imageView clickable?

Comment: I'll post my code as soon as I'm home. I worked on a brand new project with blank activity, created a layout and that's it. The only code I wrote is the "doSomething" function that only displays a Toast. Nothing crazy, I'm just playing around with Android. I made the ImageView clickable but nothing changed. I'll edit my question as soon as possible.

Comment: Set the ImageView's clickable to false.

Comment: @dharm : worked like a charm. Also I didn't think about clickable being true by defulat on ImageButton.

Comment: Yes all buttons will be clickable by default since they're buttons :)